# OSM tiles suddenly stop to download and throwing exception instead of downloading tile

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, openstreetmap, webclient

I am using OSM maps in my application and download tiles from tile https://tile.openstreetmap.org/. I am using WebClient to download the tile from OSM server. It is worked perfectly before 5 days. But suddenly, tiles not downloaded from server and maps not displayed in my application. I used below code to download tile.

```
imageBytes = await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(imageUri);
```

I have checked the source and getting the below exception in try-catch.

**The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.**

To resolve this, I set the below properties as true but still maps not displayed in my application.

```
webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
webClient.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Anyone, please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: 403 means authentication is not working.  You should contact their support.

Comment: Tile Usage Policy : https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/

Comment: This issue particularly reproduced when using web client in Xamarin.Forms Android and iOS. In Forms.UWP, we directly used url to image source and it is working fine. I just download 4 tiles only. Posted query in OSM support forum. https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/79298/osm-tiles-suddenly-stop-to-download-and-throwing-exception-instead-of-downloading-tile

Comment: @Jason There is no authentication required. It is most likely an abuse of the tile usage policy.